# Using onchange to delete other occurrences of the value in the select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a made a couple of attempts of this and I feel I was close but couldn't find the correct ajax. The select elements are made dynamically on the click of a button, and they have the same options, however what I want to happen is once you choose an option, all other occurrences of that option is removed from the select elements leaving the one you chose alone.

This one just removes from every select element that has class 'theClass' including the one you changed.

```
function removeOptions(optionValue) {
    $('.theClass option[value='+optionValue+']').remove();
}
```

I originally tried with the .each() function but couldn't call 'this' correct.

```
function removeOptions(optionValue) {
    $( ".theClass").each( function () {
        $(this + 'option[value='+optionValue+']').remove();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter the ones that you want to keep, like below.

```js
$(document).on("change", "select", function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).find("option[value='" + val + "']:not(:selected)").remove();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:** as per your comment, the following would work.

```
$(document).on("change", "select", removeOptions);

function removeOptions() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
}
```

Take a [look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/) for a working example.

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear, there is a button that generates the select elements (i.e.5) and they all have the same values, Is there a way that if i selected 2 on the 3rd select element it keeps that value and every other select loses the option for 3? The select elements are created with an onchange event that calls the function removeOptions(this.value)

Comment: Yes although this doesn't work on dynamically created selects, problem has been solved as above. Thanks!

Comment: Well it does! all you need to do is to delegate your events. See my edits.

Comment: Ah my bad, must of got confused between the two answers, Thanks!  Although as an extension to this, is there a way to repopulate the options if you change the option without creating a global array. i.e. on the first select you choose 1 then you change to 3 the other selects have no 1 or 3 but instead it adds the 1 back into the select element?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/1/).

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work, I have reproduced the code into JSfiddle, maybe it will help? http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/3/

Comment: You _again_ forgot about event delegation => [http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/4/)

Comment: Sorry I probably need a screen break, been working on this for too long haha. One problem i did find with the fiddle is that when you change one then change another it will reset the first one back to 0. i.e create 4 selects, on the first select, choose option 3 then on another select choose option 4, the first select will reset from 3 to 0 and the 3 will still be disabled on the other select elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a temporary class or a custom attribute to the target `select` to achieve your goal.

```
<select class="theClass" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="theClass" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="theClass" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

$(function() {
    $("body").on("change", ".theClass", function() {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".theClass:not(.selected)>option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").remove();
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cwfg509/1/)

Edit: Changed the `onchange` event to be fired even on dinamically created `select`s.

Comment: as an extension to this, is there a way to repopulate the options if you change the option without creating a global array. i.e. on the first select you choose 1 then you change to 3 the other selects have no 1 or 3 but instead it adds the 1 back into the select element?